# C++ Database API's - DTL

Tags: c++, mysql, oracle, api, odbc

I'm looking for a C++ API that is able to connect to different types of databases all in one; mainly MySQL, oracle and SQL Server and I believe I have found one with "DTL" ( http://dtemplatelib.sourceforge.net/ )

However, I'm struggling to connect my database on localhost. Has anyone used this before and could shed some more light on it other than what their site does with

```
DBConnection::GetDefaultConnection().Connect("UID=example;PWD=example;DSN=example;");
```

though I guess what to put in uid and pwd, I'm not sure what it's expecting in 'dsn', are there any REAL examples or have you guys used it before and could help.

Comment: Learn about the weird and wonderful world of connection strings at http://www.connectionstrings.com.

Comment: What you have in your code is a connection string, so I guess they are relevant after all.

Comment: Yes it is, which is why your example doesn't work.

Comment: I am an ODBC, C++ and database  expert who could probably be of great help to you - needless to say I won't do that from now on.

Comment: @Neil i have read the site more and was wrong - Sorry for being a jerk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ODBC library, so DSN is the ODBC data source name. On Windows, these can be configured under Administrative Tools->Data Sources.

Comment: could you divulge further on this; im experimenting it on my machine but in reality it will be running on a server; i'm a bit confused by it.

Comment: Not sure what else to add. Try reading up on ODBC. Start here for your immediate problem: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305599

Answer (score 1):

As @Dark Falcon said, the "DSN" refers to an "ODBC data source". What you get is an extra level of indirection like this:

[image]

On Windows, you normally create the ODBC data source with the "Data Sources (ODBC)" control panel, which is normally in the "Administrative Tools".

In any case, this separates the configuration/deployment "stuff" from the code. For example, if you want to use your code with a test database during development, then with the "live" database when you deploy it, you can do that without making any changes to your code, and even without changing the connection string. Instead, you change the data source to refer to production server instead of the test server.